# Setup elastic for production

Tags: production-environment, sharding, kibana, elasticsearch

I want to know what configuration setup would be ideal for my case. I have 4 servers (nodes) each with 128 GB RAM. I'll have all 4 nodes under one cluster.

Total number number of indexes would be 10, each getting data of 1500000 documents per day.

Since I'll have 4 servers (nodes) so for all these nodes I'll set `master:true`, and `data:true`, so that if one node goes down, other becomes master. Every index will have 5 shards.

I want to know which config parameters should I alter in order to gain maximum potential from elastic.

Also tell me how much memory is enough for my usage, since I'll have very frequent select queries in production (may be 1000 requests per second).

Need a detailed suggestion.s

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anyone can give you a definitive answer to exactly how to configure your servers since it is very dependent on your data structure, mapping and specific queries.

You should read this great article series by Elastic regarding [production environments](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html)